# Mysql Join 3 Tables in One Query with sorted Result

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables and want to join all in one query to show latest 10 entries by datetime.

```
t1: id, username
t2: id, id_t1, med_id, ga_id, au_id, re_id, text, datetime
t3: id, id_t1, pro_id, au_id, re_id, text, datetime
```

First I saw it would be easy with simple left join and where id, but i got double results. Then i tried inner and outer join, also group by, but the result was bad.

So my question is how can i join all without double results of the last 10 of t2 and t3?

Comment: Can you provide what you've tried, with sample data and desired results?  Perhaps you're just looking for `limit`, but I suspect it might be something else.  Hard to say without sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what exactly you are trying to acheive, but here is a clue how it could be complemented.

```
SELECT  TOP 10  DISTINCT T1.*
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.id = T2.id_t1
INNER JOIN T3 ON T1.id = T3.id_t1
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN T2.[DateTime] > T3.[DateTime] THEN 
            T2.[DateTime]
          ELSE
            T3.[DateTime]
          END) DESC
```

If you need to select field from T2 and T3, GROUP BY on all T1 field with aggregate on field from t2 and t3 is an option. Otherwise, linked-subquery is the way to go.

Comment: DISCLAIMER : This is written in TSQL

Answer (score 0):

As sgeddes commented already, it's hard to know what you need, without seeing some example data from your tables. It would really help to know what the relationship between the three tables is.

One question I have, in particular, is: how are t2 and t3 related, if at all? It looks like they might not be, as each of them has its own datetime column.

Perhaps the following could do the job, but we need some more info to know for sure:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT t1.*, t2.id, t2.au_id, t2.re_id, t2.text, t2.`datetime`, t2.med_id, t2.ga_id, NULL AS pro_id
FROM t1
    INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id_t1)
UNION
(SELECT DISTINCT t1.*, t3.id, t3.au_id, t3.re_id, t3.text, t3.`datetime`, NULL AS med_id, NULL AS ga_id, t3.pro_id
FROM t1
    INNER JOIN t3 ON t1.id = t3.id_t1)
ORDER BY datetime DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: All 3 Tables related through t1.id <->t2.id_t1 <-> t3.id_t1. Its a UserID which are the same in all 3 Tables, only in T1 are the information about this user, like Name, Username, EMail ...Rest of T2 and T3 are other information which not related through eachother. And yes i forgott to write limit 10, but i will use it. The mainproblem are the relation without double results. thx

Comment: My workaround whould be to use 2queries with limit 10 and merge that in php and select newest last 10 of that, but i think mysql is faster and needs less resources, right?

Comment: I've modified the query a bit. Is that closer to what you need?

Comment: You're right, you'll usually get the best performance if you can formulate a good SQL query that will return exactly the result set you need. Then you simply do your presentation logic in PHP. However, if your tables aren't very large (only hundreds or even thousands of rows, say), you don't need to worry about performance.

Comment: Ok thanks i will try it later on my dev machine. I always search for the best way as long it is possible and effort is ok. Here i dont know where it will go to, perhaps it will rise up to millions ;)

Comment: Hello Deniz, and many thx, i tried distinct, union and inner join, but not all together. But the main think was Null as <- now i understand that and adopte it to my tables. One thing is left, how could i get only last 10 for special t1.id? Where didnt work on any place of that.

Comment: It works, i used for the where statement a empty id, now all is fine and i have to thanks Deniz very very much, and all other for there opinion. Nice Weekend

Answer (score 0):

The following selects the username and the datetime for the last ten posts.

```
SELECT username, last_ten.`datetime` AS lastpost
FROM t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 't2' AS tab, id, `datetime`, t2.id_t1
    FROM t2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 't3' AS tab, id, `datetime`, t3.id_t1
    FROM t3
    ORDER BY datetime DESC
    LIMIT 10
) AS last_ten ON t1.id = last_ten.id_t1
```